# Fastest method to check multiple endpoints

Tags: python-3.x, performance, python-requests, multiprocessing

I'm trying to check whether certain endpoints exist for a certain domain using Python3, and I'd like to reach maximum performance. I know, the performance is dependent on my internet connection and distance to the server, but I'd like to make improvements on the programming side.

So far, I've developed this code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

url = "https://example.com/"
# imagine this list has 10000 items
tests = ['file1', 'another-file', 'test.pdf', 'item-10000']

r = requests.Session()

with requests.session() as s:
  for item in tests:
    r = requests.get(url + item)
    if r.status_code == 200:
      print("200: " + item)
    else:
      print("404: " + item)
```

However, there are several improvements which could be made, right?

- Using multiple threads, instead of executing each request per time
- The use of websockets, instead of HTTP
- Currently, I'm loading the content of the site as well, this can be skipped as I'd only like to validate whether the endpoint returns a code 200, this could save some bytes as well

Comment: The easiest approach would be to use async IO, something like https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests might be very straightforward.

Comment: ...and if you're not interested in the response bytes, and the remote server supports it properly, you can switch from GET to HEAD requests. That would speed up things considerably on the individual request level.